# How to save Login password to Keychain in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

How can I save login password to keychain? I need to see the following notification above the keyboard:

[image]

Comment: Did you try [CodeHub](https://github.com/CodeHubApp/CodeHub)? They do use the github credentials.

Comment: That is not the keystore you are referring to. That is just whatever password manager is available on the device.

Comment: @Cheesebaron do you now how to reach similar behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I hope I can help you.
Here is an Github Repository about the Keychain in Xamarin.IOS (also with sample):
 1. https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/Keychain

Also this could be helpful:
 1. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15679/how-do-i-save-my-keys-to-the-keychain-on-ios-for-later-use

EDIT: This is an unified API who could solve your Problem:
 1. https://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/05/06/announcing-keychain-net-a-unified-api-for-using-keychain-on-many-platforms/
 2. It's an NuGet Package, so you can just download it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for this:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
{
    var usernameField = new UITextField
    {
        usernameField.TextContentType = UITextContentType.Username;
    };
    var passwordField = new UITextField
    {
        passwordField.TextContentType = UITextContentType.Password;
    };
}
```

OS will detect such fields and add AutoFill option